# Workflow - Lookup of Task Name returns a Single Value

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-email, workflow-lookup

I have a Task List with columns Task Name and Due Date. I have created a workflow that if `due date=today` then send an email.

The email is sent every morning to remind people of the tasks due.

What I need in the email is all the task names with `due date=today`.

However, when I do my look up the workflow returns only one value. But in the same email I want to see all the tasks that are due today.

SharePoint warns me about this possible unique lookup but don't know how to go around it.

Comment: you need to create dictionary in workflow and in it to store all items/tasks which have due date eq. Today. You could use REST api, like here: https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Would it be easier to include in the email body a list view (i.e the upcoming view) ?

Comment: no, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option could be is to set an alert (List>Alert Me) rather than doing it through workflow e.g., You can set alerts based on the particular view. Below I have selected items 'Due Today' view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sharepointer. However seems to work only if someone has changed something.